# Instagram Graph API Business Discovery - how to get stories?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

[Business discovery doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/business_discovery) mentions nothing about fetching another account stories.
I am trying the following

```
  ?fields=business_discovery.username(marvel){stories}
```

But I get

```
"message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
```

Does it supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fetch stoires from other accounts via business discovery, but you can fetch stories from your own Instagram Business or Creator account.

You can call `/{ig-user-id}/stories` where `ig-user-id` is your own Business or Creator account.

Please be aware of these limitations:

- Responses will not include Live Video stories.
- Stories are only available for 24 hours.
- New stories created when a user reshares a story will not be returned.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories